# How to jump out of brackets in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ide

Does **VSCode** have the ability to tab out of auto-completed brackets? As in, when you press **"tab" key** near a closing bracket, the cursor will **jump over** it instead of adding a new tab. This is a feature in **Pycharm** and I am used to it. But in VSCode you must use **arrow keys** to do so.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for the [TabOut](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=albert.TabOut) plugin for VSCode

Comment: you are welcome ^_^
additionly , I recommend a vscode extension to you, it is "macros"
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geddski.macros ,
very useful